# change PSQL default user

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1, psql

K- so hopefully explaining why I'm trying to do this will help.  I do most of my dev work on a company-provided laptop; but when I get home, I would like to use my desktop.  I have a number of rails projects wherein the username & password are already defined as 'postgres', so I don't want to change the username & password in the .yml files for these projects just to get it to work on my desktop.  Too much of a headache.  So, all I want to do is change my postgres environment to look for the username 'postgres' as default.  I also don't want to have to pass -U or -W every single time I want to log in.  So...

How can you change the default role for psql/postgres?
From command line, if I type in:

```
$ psql
```

I get back

```
psql: FATAL:  role "crash" does not exist
```

It's looking for "crash" because that's my user account for my PC login- however, I want my default username to be "postgres" not "crash".  How can I change which role PSQL is looking for on init?

As it turns out, Google has a number of resources regarding creating a new role for postgres, or changing the password, or any number of other useful information; however, I've been searching for hours and I can't find anything specific to changing which role postgres should use for default.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Sys- ubuntu 12.04 lts
64-bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's introductory information on using PostgreSQL on Ubuntu [on the Ubuntu Community site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).

You may also find the [PostgreSQL manual on client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html) useful.

You'll want to [set the `PGUSER` environment variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) to override the default user.

It can also be useful to define a *service* for `libpq` in `~/.pg_service.conf`, per [the documentation on `libpq` service definitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html); you can then refer to that in `psql` with `service=myservice`, avoiding the need to repeat details. This is the "right" way to handle this problem - define a service, refer to the service in the `database.yml` and have a `.pg_service.conf` file outside revision control specify what that actually means, with a template copy in revision control for convenience.

(The `~/.psqlrc` file may also be useful See [the documentation for psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).)

Shell aliases can be handy too. I often do things like add

```
alias psomedb 'psql "service=somedb"'
```

to my `~/.bashrc` for convenient access to frequently used DBs and hosts.

The [`~/.pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) may be used to store passwords for various host/port/db/user combinations.

All that being said, it's a *terrible* idea to work routinely as the `postgres` user. It should *not* be your default. Create an ordinary user, possibly one with `CREATEDB` rights, but not a superuser. Use that user for most tasks and only switch to a superuser (`postgres` or some other user you created for the purpose) when you *need* superuser rights. It's the same principle as "don't work as root, `sudo` only when required instead".

Comment: I don't see how you can use .psqlrc to set default connection info - please could you clarify?

Comment: @hbn You're right, and I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bash snippet to use the first username specified in `~/.pgpass` :

```sh
alias psql=psql_wrapper

psql_wrapper() {
    local args=("$@") username="" override=1
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        if [[ $1 == "-h" ]]; then
            username=$(grep $2 ~/.pgpass | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 4)
        elif [[ $1 == "-U" ]]; then
            override=""
        fi
        shift
    done
    if [[ $username && $override ]]; then
        echo "-U" "$username"
        args+=("-U" "$username")
    fi
    \psql "${args[@]}"
}
```